# How is strtok really implemented? (performance question)

Tags: c

Consider the following two implementations of some `ignore_delims` functions:

```
char* ignore_delims_v1(char* input, char* delims)
{
     while (in(*input, delims))
        ++input;

     return input;
}

char* ignore_delims_v2(char* input, char* delims)
{
     ssize_t len = strlen(delims);

     do {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            input = skip_char(input, delims[i]);          
     } while(in(*input, delims));

     return input;
}
```

where `in(char c, char* test)` is a function that returns `1` if `c` is in `test` (by checking `test` char by char against `c`), while `skip_char(char* str, char c)` returns the first occurence `!= c`.

The second version should be statistically faster if the following assumption is usually true:

- Most of the tokens, when separated by more than one character, don't usually mix more than one different character.

For example, this:

```
field1  field2\t\tfield3  field4\n
field1 field2\tfield3\t\t field4\n
```

is much more common than this:

```
field1 \t field2\t\t field3 field4  \n
\tfield1  field2\tfield3  \tfield4\n
```

In the first example, each pair of fields if either separated by  , or by `\t` or by `\n`, but no separating-string contains more than one different character. However, the second example have "separating-strings" containing more than one different character each.

I claim that most of the time, the first example represents better reality than the second, at least when you are parsing text that aren't natural language, like tables, output of commands, etc, which are things that are parsed all the time.

If my assumptions are true, then I think the second implementation schema must be statistically much faster than the first one because it tries to consume at once contiguous sequences of a same delimiter, which is a much more common situation than the first. The number of performed character checks I think would be greaty reduced.

And now the final question, when `strtok` have to find the next token and have to skip separators first, is `strtok` using an implementation more similar to my first version, or more similar to the second?

Comment: A possible `strtok` implementation uses a `static` local variable to keep track of where the last returned token ends, and where to start searching for the next. If the first argument is a `NULL` pointer, this local variable is used, otherwise the passed argument is used, and the local variable is reset.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it doesn't change the question. At the next call, `strtok` have to ignore delims to find the start of the next token. That is the situation I'm talking about: skipping delims.

Comment: When `strtok` finds a delimiter, it changes that delimiter in the searched string to the string null-terminator, skips all delimiter characters, and save a pointer to the character *after* the delimiters (which will be the start of the *next* token). The pointer to the start of the current token is then returned. Exactly how the function skips delimiters is undefined and implementation specific, but a simple loop over the input string while the current character is found in the delimiter set is one such possibility. There might be other ways.

Comment: There are quite a few open-source implementations of `strtok` available for reference if you want to see specific implementations. Which is "better" depends on your use-case. You just have to test and benchmark and measure to find the one that fits your requirements best.

Comment: One simple way to speed the "is member of delimiter set" up would be to use a bitset to preprocess the delimiter string. 256 bits fit in 4 64-bit numbers, which can be kept in registers or on the stack.

Comment: @TomKarzes I know. I just wanted to keep the question simple and remove that extra line. Besides, the compiler can smartly see that the string is not modified and thus (I hope) will apply that optimization. Since `strlen` received a constant pointer, it knows `strlen` won't modify the string, and the loop isn't modifying the string either so...

Comment: "_[not] separated by a heterogeneous admixture..._" The words (tokens) making up the text of OP's question are demarcated by `",.:? \"\n"`. An example of a heterogeneous admixture if ever there was one.

Comment: @ABu how would the compiler know that `in` isn't modifying the string, esp. if `in` isn't known until link time?

Comment: It is pretty senseless to discuss performance without a specific system in mind. Word size, alignment, presence/absence of data cache and/or instruction cache... and so on. "Big O" is mostly stone age stuff for these reasons - an algorithm which was in theory the most efficient in the 1980s is not necessarily so nowadays. Brute force search might be significantly faster than binary search etc.

Comment: @Luatic Careful... Subsequent calls to `strtok()` need not use the same delimiter(s)... That bit collection would, therefore, have to be reestablished on each invocation...

Comment: @Lundin I know, but I cannot think a way where having better "branch accuracy" would give you worst results. I used `O(1)` as a way to say: you discard more possible options faster: "check one char and go; where are not going here", while by `O(n)` I meant: "you have to check one by one because you don't know where is the last delimiter".

Comment: @Lundin By declaring the signature as `const char* restrict input`, I guess. Anyway, you moved from talking about `strlen` (which of course in real code I won't put it there), to `in`.

Comment: @Fe2O3 of course; still it would likely be worth it, assuming the input string is significantly longer than the charset.

Comment: @TomKarzes I've updated the question. I hope is better written now.

Comment: In many implementations (see for example https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.17.90/source/string/strpbrk.c#L30), the first strategy is used. I doubt it worth the effort to use such an optimisation in such a general purpose function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed implementation relies on the functions `in` and `skip_char`, which you did not post. If `in` has a loop to test the character against all accepted ones, transposing the loops to skip sequences of identical separators efficiently might have some benefits in some cases.

Note however that your approach is inefficient to skip the words instead of sequences of separators.  Furthermore it would use more tests if the string of separators has a single character.

Most implementations of `strtok` rely on `strspn()`, `strcspn()`, `strpbrk` or custom code... potentially taking advantage of some common cases:

- they can test if the separator string has a single character and use simple loops to skip past the separators or to the next one.
- for longer separator sets, they can use a bit array to perform the equivalent of the `in` function in a single test: `if (a[c >> 5] & (1U << (c & 31)))`
- they can use elaborate macros to test for single character strings at compile time.

Finally, `strtok` is probably not worth optimizing: it should not even be used anymore because of its confusing semantics.  This function uses a static internal state that makes it non-reentrant and possibly non thread safe.  Use `strtok_r` instead, or a combination of `strspn`, `strcspn`, `strpbrk`.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` is part of the implementation, so there is no single answer to this. You can check for instance [glibc](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.17.90/source/string/strtok.c), which does not include your optimization.

If you search the literature for string search algorithms, you'll find that there are quite a few reasonable approaches. `strtok` is a simple, not-optimized-for-your-data function in the standard library, and it's definitely outdated. A clear indication of this is that it's not reentrant. Use `strtok_r` instead.

Comment: Well, *actually* you should use `strsep`, which unlike `strtok_r` had actual thought put into its ergonomics.